Setting caret Y position
I have been developing a custom integration of a TextArea using Jpanel but am having trouble drawing the caret correctly, I use LineBreakMeasurer to draw the lines of text and the caret is getting the correct X position but when there's a line break it stays in the first line.
Here is the paintComponent method.
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.setFont(font);
    
        ry = (float) 3 * getHeight() / 4;
        if(!this.content.toString().isEmpty()) {
    
            TreeMap<Integer, IndexedTextLayout> layoutTreeMap = new TreeMap<>();
            AttributedCharacterIterator paragraph = new AttributedString(this.content.toString()).getIterator();
            int paragraphStart = paragraph.getBeginIndex();
            int paragraphEnd = paragraph.getEndIndex();
            FontRenderContext frc = g.getFontMetrics().getFontRenderContext();
            LineBreakMeasurer lineMeasurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(paragraph, frc);
            float breakWidth = (float) getSize().width;
            float drawPosY = 0;
            lineMeasurer.setPosition(paragraphStart);
    
            int index = 1;
            while (lineMeasurer.getPosition() < paragraphEnd) {
                int layoutStartIndex = lineMeasurer.getPosition();
                int next = lineMeasurer.nextOffset(breakWidth);
                int limit = next;
                if (limit <= this.content.toString().length()) {
                    for (int i = lineMeasurer.getPosition(); i < next; ++i) {
                        char c = this.content.toString().charAt(i);
                        if (c == '\n') {
                            limit = i + 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                TextLayout layout = lineMeasurer.nextLayout(breakWidth,limit,false);
    
                layoutTreeMap.put(layoutStartIndex, new IndexedTextLayout(index,layout));
    
                float drawPosX = layout.isLeftToRight() ? 0 : breakWidth - layout.getAdvance();
                AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(drawPosX, drawPosY);
                drawPosY += layout.getAscent();
                layout.draw((Graphics2D) g, drawPosX, drawPosY);
                g.setColor(getForeground());
                drawPosY += layout.getDescent() + layout.getLeading();
                index++;
            }
    
            if(!layoutTreeMap.isEmpty()){
                Entry<Integer,IndexedTextLayout> currentLayoutEntry = layoutTreeMap.floorEntry(cursorPosition);
                IndexedTextLayout currentLayout = currentLayoutEntry.getValue();
                int cursorPositionOffset = cursorPosition - currentLayoutEntry.getKey();
                AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0, currentLayout.getLayout().getBounds().getHeight());
    
                Shape[] carets = currentLayout.getLayout().getCaretShapes(cursorPositionOffset);
                Shape caret = at.createTransformedShape(carets[0]);
                caret.getBounds().setLocation(caret.getBounds().x,  (int) (currentLayout.getIndex() * currentLayout.getLayout().getDescent() + currentLayout.getLayout().getLeading()));
                g2.setColor(getForeground());
                g2.draw(caret);
            }
        }
    }

Image example of the problem
I tried setting the Y coordinate in the bounds of the Caret shape but i doesn't seem to do anything when it's actually drawn.

your AffineTransform translates only on ony axis - as the caret is moved in one direction this could mean that you have to translate on two axes.
But your code does too much for a proper analysis and you didn't provide a proper [mre] to analyze it further, so please try to refactor that method into smaller methods and if you want us to help further, provide a bit more code so we could reproduce that example from the screenshot.
